# How to create a survey using Twitter Tweets

Tags: twitter

Here in this site http://loveorhatexmas.com/

they have created a survey and i think they are checking the hash codes like #loveXMass and #hateXMass in tweets and showing the result..

but i am not sure how they are checking all the tweets sent by anyone all around the world?
is there anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They might be using the [Twitter API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554648/FrontPage), perhaps the [Search](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search) functionality.